# Showing form inside another form in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main form which has all the controls and i have to create a new form for help window which guides you to use the main form.
I did check about the mdi container but it looks a bit odd to see 2 forms inside another form.
Is there any other way for embedding my main form inside another form? like docking?

Comment: Would Creating an UserControl from your MainForm and embedding that into your 2nd form work?

Comment: no i already have atleast 3 user controls in my main form...Now i have to create a new form which includes both my main form and the help form...

Comment: Is there a reason it has to be a Window? are you going to need the functions of a window like minimise, close etc?

Comment: No i dont but i could not get the main-form(that has all controls) docked into another form. Thats when i thought of mdi container

Comment: why not just dock the `Content` of the mainform

Comment: @varun there is nothing to stop you from having usercontrols embedded in another usercontrol. If you are not needing functions unique to a window that is the way to go.

Comment: i have already docked a lot of things to the main form...its just becoming too complex...is there any way to dock the whole form itself at once?

Comment: If you are using WPF you are not allowed to Dock a Window inside of another window. It gives an error stating that a Window can not be a Child of Visual. If this was WinForms you would be able to do it by setting the TopLevel Property to False. As I stated earlier I beleive that an UserControl Containing the Contents of your MainForm would be the way to go.

Comment: @varun rethink your approach. It has been proven that MDI is the worst UI idea ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
<DockPanel>
    <Frame Name="frame" NavigationUIVisibility="Visible" Source="SomePage.xaml" />
</DockPanel>
```